# Looking for a machine learning algorithm that can classify line plots into two groups?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, matlab

I have a dataset of many 2-D line plots that represent height versus position measured from an AFM.

I am interested in training a model by classifying these lines into two groups: presence of a defect and no presence.

I believe a neural network would be appropriate for this since there are other features in the line plots that I want to be able to ignore.

The problem is that I am just starting by taking a certification course on machine learning but that hasn't given me enough information to develop one on my own. I have worked with a segnet based neural network but at a very user oriented level.

So I was wondering if anyone knew of an open-source algorithm that I could feed these lines into (maybe as vectors?) to train a model?

Comment: What is AFM short for?

Comment: Would you call this an image classification problem?

Comment: AFM stands for atomic force microscopy, basically it just gives me height measurements of a sample along a straight line.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is an image classification problem because I was hoping to just use vectors holding the data for training a model, I don't know if training it as an image classification would be correct since the vast majority of the image is essentially blank which will heavily skew the training.

Comment: What is a defect in this task, is it about the position/orientation of the line or about how noisy the lines are? Your dataset is annotated, right? (I mean you have the correct label for every image)

Comment: The defect is a somewhat wide dip in the height towards the center. The problem is that there can be other features that make a rule based separation not tenable. For instance, a sample without a dip in the center could have a cut or a sample with a dip could also have a cut in it.

Basically, I figure it should be possible somehow to feed about 500 correctly categorized x-y plots into some neural network, and then have a model that will predict whether or not a new x-y plot will have the dip or not.